# How to set "Other LInk Flag"?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

I am using Twitterkit in my app.

I installed it by Pod.

Today, I removed the "TwitterKit" from "Other Link Flag" by accident.

The xcode is always showing "clang: error: no such file or directory: 'TwitterKit'" error after I add "TwitterKit" back to "Other Link Flag".

Any clue how to deal with this build issue?

Thank you in advanced.

[2016-10-10 Update]

Other Linker Flags:
Need *-framework* item before each item.
Then it should be added as below:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Build Settings --> Linking --> "Other Linker Flags" include 
-framework "TwitterCore" and
-framework "TwitterKit"

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution is working for me. I didn't add "-framework" item before "TwitterCore"